# Printing a variable in a file along with some existing columns

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a long file with three columns. I want to add a column (as the first column) with '5' for the first 200 lines and then '6' for the next 200 lines and so on...

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what your file looks like, include around 5 lines or so.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk 'BEGIN { c1 = 5 } { print c1, $0 } FNR%200 == 0 { ++c1 }' file
```

This would initiate a variable, `c1`, to 5 at the start of the `awk` program.  All input lines are then printed prepended by the current value of this variable.

For any line whose line number (`FNR`) is a multiple of 200, this variable would be incremented by 1 after printing the line.

The increments to `c1` would happen after printing line 200, 400, etc.

By default, the separator between the number and the original data will be a space character.  Change it to a tab (or whatever you want) by setting `OFS` in the `BEGIN` block (or use `-v OFS='\t'` on the command line of `awk`):

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; c1 = 5 } { print c1, $0 } FNR%200 == 0 { ++c1 }' file
```

Redirect the output to a new filename to save it.